# Reload the .profile file

Tags: bash, load, profile

I've modified the .profile file of a user. It contains some new environement vars, how can i reload this file without restarting the server ?

The .profile file is only charged when the system boots or in any other case ??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally the file gets parsed on startup of a new shell (not at system boot!). So you can just start another shell and your changes to `~/.profile` will be present. However, you can also "source" the file in the current shell session:

```
source ~/.profile
```

Note that `source` is just human readable shortcut for the `.` command. So, you can also issue

```
. ~/.profile
```

---

Thanks to @chepner for explaining that `source` is an alias of `.` and not vise versa.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
$ . ~/.profile
```

This is doing the same as:

```
$ source ~/.profile
```

The file will be executed (interpreted) by the current shell, all changes to environment variables will affect your current session.